# Polynomial time for a graph algorithm

Tags: asymptotics

Suppose an algorithm $A$ which, given a graph $G$ on $n$ vertices (represented in, say,
adjacency matrix form) and some parameter $C$, runs in time $T = O\bigl(n^2\cdot \sqrt{C}\bigr)$. Is the algorithm taking polynomial time or pseudo polynomial time?

Comment: How does $C$ depend on $n$? Do you know something about this?

Comment: C depends on n but I dont know how.